# Can't ensure thread safety despite @MainActor

Tags: swift

I have a setup where I have an `async` function which fetches items from an API, and then triggers a snapshot rebuild for a `UICollectionView`.

When the `UICollectionView` detects that less than 5 rows remain in the data set, it called `updateData()` to fetch the next 10 items.

The problem I am facing is the `collectionView(willDisplay cell)` method can execute twice before `updateData` has finished, leading to two API requests using the same cursor, which causes `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` to crash as there are now duplicate identifiers.

My setup looks like this:

```swift
@MainActor
internal func updateItems() async throws {
    let newItems = try await NetworkService.shared.getItems(limit: 10, cursor: cursor)
    self.cursor = newItems.last
    for item in newItems {
        self.items.insert(item)
    }
    self.itemIDs.append(contentsOf: newItems(\.id))
    self.buildSnapshot()
}

func buildSnapshot() {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, UUID>()
    snapshot.appendSections([.allItems])
    snapshot.appendItems(self.items)
    self.dataSource.apply(snapshot)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (self.itemIDs.count - indexPath.row) < 5 {
        Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
            try await self.updateItems()
        }
    }
}
```

So if `try await self.updateItems()` is called twice too close together, things crash.

Can anyone offer any advice to solve this issue?

I have tried using a variable `fetchInProgress` and checking that within `updateItems` with no luck. I have tried annotating the function with `@MainActor` (but I don't think I want the whole thing to run on the main queue anyhow), and tried using `{ @MainActor in`  with the `Task`.

Comment: Why not store the last cursor when `updateItems` has finished and only allow execution if it's different than the last.

Comment: That feels like a bandaid rather than an a bug fix. I don't want it to be possible for this to execute twice, it's a needless waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to prevent duplicate Tasks from firing I would try:

1. In your class add a property:

```swift
private var updateTask: Task<Void, Error>?
```

2. Then in your `collectionView` function:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (self.itemIDs.count - indexPath.row) < 5 && updateTask == nil { 
        updateTask = Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
            try await self.updateItems()
            self.updateTask = nil
        }
    }
}
```

This way, your task will only be non-nil in the case that it has been started and not finished. If we find it to be non-nil then we do not create it again, thus avoiding duplicate tasks.

This solution I modified from [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-role-tasks-play-in-swift-concurrency/#referencing-and-cancelling-a-task), which I'd recommend taking a look at as well.

Also, here is a simple playground example I came up with:

```swift
class MyClass {
    private var updateTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    func updateItems() async throws {
        // Waits 1 second
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        print("Hello World")
    }
    
    func doUpdate() {
        if updateTask == nil {
            updateTask = Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
                try await self.updateItems()
                self.updateTask = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateTooOften() {
        for _ in 0..<3 {
            doUpdate()
        }
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.updateTooOften() // prints "Hello World" once
```

Here `doUpdate()` is called twice more before the task is finished, but we only execute the task once and see a single "Hello World" printed.